# How to run a model for say 30 replications using AnyLogic?

Tags: output, replication, anylogic

I want to run my model for 30 replications without interuptions.
My next question is how to save the results of all replications.
I get the results from different timeplots (I copy the entire output) and use the output of several timemeasureends.
How can I export them?

---

Answer (score 0):

Use a "Parameter Variation" experiment and create 30 replications with that, see https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/parameter-variation.html#stochastic

Re the other questions: Please always open new issues for new questions and avoid open ended "how do I do X" questions ([some tips for AnyLogic users here](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow)). For open-ended questions, better use the LinkedIn forum, see [this intro](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community).